# How to display a string with a delay in between words in Swift?

Tags: string, swift, delay

So I've tried using Matt's delay code but it does not seem to fit my purpose. I'm writing a Swift app and would like to be able to display a string (say a word at a time) with a delay in between. Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: There must be kind of a `sleep(time)` or `wait(time)` function.

Comment: Don't use sleep or wait! Maybe NSTimer can be of some use to you?

Comment: NSTimer and a selector are your best bet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTypeWriter: UITextView!

    let words = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Nam liber te conscient to factor tum poen legum odioque civiuda. Hello World !!!".componentsSeparatedByString(" ")

    var counter = 0
    var timer:NSTimer?

    // create a method to add one word at a time to your text view
    func addWord(){

        // make sure you only update your text field if you have a corresponding item in your array
        if counter < words.count {
            myTypeWriter.text = "\(myTypeWriter.text) \(words[counter])"
       // invalidate your timer when it is finished
        } else {
            timer?.invalidate()
        }
        counter++
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.25, target: self, selector: "addWord", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a delay of four seconds between two words.  You dont say how many words you need to do this with and without any context or you posting any code its not easy to understand your requirements.  However this will provide a delay between two strings

```
self.mystring.text = "some word"

let seconds = 4.0
let delay = seconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)  // nanoseconds per seconds
var dispatchTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))

dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

   // Performed with delay
    self.mystring.text = "a different word"

})
```

Comment: Upvoted for using the more modern Grand Central Dispatch approach. NSTimers are so 2009!